# RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is absolutely not recommended

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-sqs, supervisord

When I am daemonizing the celery worker it is giving me the above warning along with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py",
> line 205, in start
> self.blueprint.start(self) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
> line 119, in start
> step.start(parent) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
> line 370, in start
> return self.obj.start()  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
> line 316, in start
> blueprint.start(self)  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
> line 119, in start
> step.start(parent) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
> line 592, in start
> c.loop(*c.loop_args()) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py",
> line 91, in asynloop
> next(loop) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py",
> line 299, in create_loop
> item() 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py",
> line 170, in **call**
> return self.throw() 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py",
> line 167, in **call**
> retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs) 
>   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py",
> line 336, in _schedule_queue
> queue, callback=promise(self._loop1, (queue,)),  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py",
> line 352, in _get_bulk_async
> return self._get_async(queue, maxcount, callback=callback)   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py",
> line 362, in _get_async
> qname, count=count, connection=self.asynsqs,   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py",
> line 456, in asynsqs
> region=self.region  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/sqs/connection.py",
> line 27, in **init**
> **kwargs   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/connection.py",
> line 186, in **init**
> **http_client_params)  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/connection.py",
> line 151, in **init**
> self._httpclient = http_client or get_client()   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/**init**.py",
> line 22, in get_client
> client = hub._current_http_client = Client(hub, **kwargs)   File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/**init**.py",
> line 13, in Client
> return CurlClient(hub, **kwargs)  
>  File "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py",
> line 43, in **init**
> raise ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.') ImportError: The curl client requires the pycurl library.

Above error is a little strange since the pycurl is already installed. And when I change `user=nobody` then the following error is occurring:

> File
> "/var/app/venv/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 135, in check_apps_ready
> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha after hours of headbanging.The error **ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.')** was resolved with the help of [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4654#issuecomment-682034915) github comment.As [Safwan Samsudeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13981530/safwan-samsudeen) pointed out the warning ***RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is absolutely not recommended***
is not an issue.So my .conf files are the same and I uninstalled pycurl and again reinstalled it using the command **pip install pycurl --compile --global-option="--with-openssl" --no-cache-dir'**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#running-the-worker-with-superuser-privileges-root). It's a warning, though, not an error (see the [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/platforms.py#L789)). Running Celery under root is an error only when you allow pickle serialization which is not enabled by default (see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#accept-content)).

Hope that helps fix your problem.